# How to create Jar file with external folders and Jars

Tags: java, spring, jar, executable-jar

I made a simple standard-lone java Application using `Spring,Apache Camel,Activemq` for processing messages.

Note: My Application don't have any GUI.

My project structure is in the following way.

[image]

`SACLib` folder have nearly 70 external jars(all Spring,Camel and Activemq corresponding jars).

It's working fine in `Eclipse`. SO Now We want to deploy into `Jar` file.I tried in `Eclipse`,But I didn't seen `Rod1,Rod2,Copy1 and SACLib` folders in my `Jar`file.

after Deploying `Jar`, If I run `FirstConsumer.java` it runs `Rod1-->ThMapInfratab1-2.exe` file. For this I mention Real paths of `.exe` file.

How can I make Jar file with including all my folders.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is a kind of work that is typically done with build automation tools like [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/), [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/), so you can investigate there if you want to make this happen automatically next time.

But, if you want to do it manually...

First, you project needs a `META-INF` folder where you will place a file called a `MANIFEST`.

That manifest contains a `Main-Class` entry pointing to you main class. You can read about this in the Java Tutorial: [Setting Application's Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).

But it can also contain a `Class-Path` entry, pointing to all other jars required by your application and that should be loaded by the executable jar.

You can read about it the Java Tutorial: [Adding Classes to your Jar Class Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).

If you are building your executable jar with Eclipse, it will let you choose the MANIFEST file that you want to use during the creation process.

Now, if you want to use build automation tools, there are other answers here that explain how to do it:

- [Creating a bundle jar with ant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1821803/697630)
- [How to create executable jar with dependencies with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/574594/697630)
- [How to export an executable jar in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14639536/697630)

Answer (score 2):

simply using ant download it , and then make a build.xml file and put it

Here's an simple example of an ant target that will create a jar (named test.jar) that includes all jar files under the lib directory. Maybe this will solve your problem?

for using apache ant, see this

http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html

Comment: I never use Ant , can you provide any tutorials or explain clearly.