# Gradle/Groovy refer to "file-wide/global" variable from inside block

Tags: gradle, global-variables

In my build file I have the following line:

```
version = '1.1.2'
```

I want to make an executable "fat jar" using Shadow Jar (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639536/how-to-export-a-executable-jar-in-gradle-and-this-jar-can-run-as-it-include-ref/41728433#41728433)) and then copy this to another directory (see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30637190/595305)).  But I want to incorporate the project's version number into the name of the jar file so as not to overwrite the existing version.

The [Shadow Plugin User Guide](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/) explains how to set the name:

```
shadowJar {
    baseName = 'shadow'
    classifier = null
    version = "7.7.7"
}
```

... but how might I set the variable `version` here to use the outer (file-wide/global...) variable `version`?

Comment: version = project.version

Comment: Ha... thanks very much.  Add an answer if you want some points.  To clarify also, if anyone's interested, the line setting the project.version variable must come physically ***before*** the reference to it in this task.  Somehow a Gradle newb like myself assumes that the variables will all be set in the "first life cycle" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a gradle script, there's a [Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) instance in scope which everything delegates to. When you say `version = '1.1.2'` it's actually invoking

```
getProject().setVersion('1.1.2')
```

In your shadowJar closure there's a version higher up in the scope which is hiding the project version. So you can do

```
shadowJar {
    version = project.version
    ...
}
```